# how to monitor network/cpu/memory/disk usage by each Rails app

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, nginx, ruby-on-rails

I run many Rails app on linode VPS.
I want to charge my customers by their usage,
Is there anyway to monitor each Rails app's usage?
I need these information network/cpu/memory/disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

Would [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/server-monitoring) help?

It monitors web applications usage.